# How do I call a static method of another class

Tags: c++, windows, oop, mfc, static-methods

I have a class, lets say `CAppPath` which has a static method:

```
public:
    static CString GetAppPath();
```

and in `CAppPath.cpp` it's defined as:

```
CString CAppPath::GetAppPath()
{

    return "C:\..\MypAth";
}
```

Now I have another class `CXMLHandler`, and I have included `CAppPath.h` in it. But how do I call the `GetAppPath()` method? I've tried:

```
#include "CAppPath.h"
void CXMLHandler::MyMethod
{
CNDSClientDlg->GetAppPath();
}
```

but it doesn't work. How should I access this method? Since it is a static method, do I need to create a object of the class or should I make the class itself static?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You only need to use the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B) `::` to qualify the method with the name of the class that exposes it:

```
CString appPath = CAppPath::GetAppPath();
```

Comment: Thanks, In that case Do I need the method as static?

Comment: @Subhen, yes, you do. If the method is not static, you'll have to create a new instance of the `CAppPath` class in order to call the `GetAppPath()` method on that instance.