# Error C2143: missing ';' before '->'

Tags: c#, c++-cli, managed

I've searched here and the internet and no one seems to be having a similar problem to me and I can't quite figure out why I cannot get this to work.

The line that is preventing me from compiling is:

```
LitCiterCommon::LitCiterTrace->Init();
```

If I call `LitCiterTrace.Init()` from a different file (c#) it compiles just fine, but for some reason I cannot call it from managed cpp.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using :: instead of -> ?

Comment: `Init` is probably a static function. You need to call it as such: `LitCiterCommon::LitCiterTrace::Init();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Init` is a [static method then it would not be any different than in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365982/how-do-i-call-a-static-method-of-another-class):

```
// this is no different than calling a static member method in C++
LitCiterCommon::LitCiterTrace::Init();
```

Comment: Haha, I didn't even notice that my partner changed it to a static method while I was gone...I really need to stop taking vacations away from this codebase.

Thanks again for catching my stupidity.