# Why does console need two colons in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In C#, we do:

```
Console.WriteLine("C#");
```

In C++/CLI we use this syntax to use console object.

```
Console::WriteLine("C++ CLI");
```

We are using a .NET object `Console` in both places so why do we access its member function `WriteLine()` with dot(.) in C# project but with two colons in C++/CLI project?

From a book on C++/CLI, it says `Console` is a class in `System` namespace so why the :: operator? Is it a different `consol`e class all together? Is the `system` namespace also different from the one in C#? if so why they named it the same?

Comment: @HansPassant ".net code exclusively uses the heap" is not precise (value types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because WriteLine is a static method:

```
// C#
public static void WriteLine (string value);
```

and [scope resolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B) `::` is used to call static methods in C++

See [How do I call a static method of another class (in C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365982/how-do-i-call-a-static-method-of-another-class)