# C++, call function using class name

Tags: c++, class

In C++ how may I write a function that is being called using the class name?
for example if I have a class called `test` I want to call a function called `calc` like this:

```
test::calc();
```

and not via an object of the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a static method of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365982/how-do-i-call-a-static-method-of-another-class)

Answer (score 2):

```
class test{
public:
   static void calc(){ /*do stuff */ }
};
```

See [static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Test {
 public:
     static void calc() { /* ... */ }
 };

 int main() 
 {  
    Test::calc();
 }
```

Essentially an ordinary function within the namespace of the class.